# Returning binary data with web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following controller method which returns a byte array.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        var model = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(model));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

I think this is an older way of implementing this functionality with web api.  Is there a more "modern" version?

For example, is returning a `Task<IHttpActionResult>` the preferred way now?  And if so, what would be the code to return the byte array from above?

Comment: I do not believe there is any *new* way to handle this. Web API 2 has not changed. I see there is no `await` inside your method, for this reason you should avoid making it `async`, just use `HttpResponseMessage` as return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comment pointed out. I dont think there is a new way to do this. But if you would like to return an `IHttpActionResult` instead, there is a base method that returns a `ResponseMessageResult`:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var model = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(model))
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return ResponseMessage(result);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, to return binary data in AspNetCore WebApi2 if anyone needs it:

```
[Route("api/v1/export/excel")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAsExcel()
{
    var exportStream = new MemoryStream();
    _exportService.ExportAllToExcel(exportStream);
    // Rewind the stream before we send it.
    exportStream.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(exportStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
}
```